# enum value fetch by key in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, enums, django-views

I have implemented the choices in Subcategory Size filed,

```
SIZE = [['EXSMALL','Extra Small'],['SMALL','Small'],['MEDIUM','Medium'],['LARGE','Large'],['XTRALARGE','Extra Large']]

class Sub_Category(models.Model):


    subcategory_size = MultiSelectField(choices=SIZE, max_length=50, default="", null=True, blank=True)
```

I have size value 2, and i want to fetch the 'Medium'.

> I want to know how to fetch value by index value of enum ?

Comment: It's unclear what you call `value`, `index value` and `enum`. Please give an example.

Comment: `SIZE[size_value][1]` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your coorrecty, you need to define `__str__` function inside your model Class:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.get_subcategory_size_display()
```

or directly in `views.py`

```
cs = Sub_Category.objects.get(pk=1)
print(cs.get_subcategory_size_display())
```

or in template

```
{{ sub_category.get_subcategory_size_display }}
```

[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)